# Make root point to static webpage in Vapor

Tags: vapor

I have a static web page stored in the Public folder of my Vapor server. It has an index.html file. However when I navigate to root (http://localhost:8080) it displays `Not found`.

What I need to do make root point to index.html?

Answer (score 2):

On Vapor 3, adding a home route worked for me. Specifically, I added the route in `routes.swift` like this:

```swift
router.get { req -> Future<View> in
    let dir = DirectoryConfig.detect()
    let path = dir.workDir + "/Public/index.html"
    return try req.view().render(path)
}
```

Comment: The answer should relate to version 4

Answer (score 2):

For Vapor 4 ...

Inside routes.swift:

```
app.get { req -> EventLoopFuture<View> in
    return req.view.render(app.directory.publicDirectory + "index.html")
}
```

This assumes you have a "Public" folder in your project directory root with an index.html file inside.

Also, in configure.swift:

```
app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: app.directory.publicDirectory))
```

Build project, run server, and point a browser to localhost:8080, you don't even have to specify localhost:8080/index.html, it just goes.

Comment: Cannot find 'app' in scope

Comment: In routes.swift, place the code inside the routes() function, in configure.swift, paste the code inside the configure() function. The app.middleware call in configure.swift should actually already be there in the file as a comment, just uncomment that line. The new route, needs to be added to the routes.swift routes() function. There should already be some routes there, just emulate them.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a middleware to handle this.

```swift
import Vapor

final class IndexPageMiddleware: Middleware {
    func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        // check if path is /
        guard request.url.path == "/" else {
            // otherwise pass to next responder
            return next.respond(to: request)
        }
        // respond with index
        let indexPath = request.application.directory.publicDirectory + "/index.html"
        let response = request.fileio.streamFile(at: indexPath)
        return request.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(response)
    }
}
```

then in `configure.swift` add the following

```swift
app.middleware.use(IndexPageMiddleware())
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it is because I'm using Vapor 3.0. But `request` has no `application` parameter and I'm not finding how to get the path to public directory. Any idea?

Comment: I almost forgot already how it was implemented in Vapor 3 honestly. You could try to use `DirectoryConfiguration.detect().publicDirectory` and it will work, but it'd be better to store path to public directory into `storage` (it is kinda cache) to not detect that path everytime.

Comment: I wasn't able to make this answer work. At least on Vapor 3. I'm going to post an answer that works for me in Vapor 3. In any case, thank you very much imike